# How can I submit multiple forms using Django and JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

I'm working on an app that displays a form on the index page, into which you can enter information to eventually calculate a gross total and output other details based on the form inputs.

- My form inherits from form.Forms.
- A button, "Add row", creates as many copies of this row as needed.

Each form contains a form with the ID "calc-form". My problem is that only one form is included in the POST method. I would like to process all forms with one click.

How can I include all additional forms in the POST method when I click "Calculate"?

**index.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
{% load static %}

<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'app.js' %}"></script>

<table id="table-id">
  <tr id='table-row'>
    <form id="calc-form" action="{% url 'result' %}" method="post">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {% for field in form %}
      <td>{{ field|as_crispy_field }}</td>
      {% endfor %}
    </form>
  </tr>
</table>
<br>

<input type="submit" value="Calculate" form="calc-form">
<button type="button" id="add-row-btn" onclick="addRow()">Add row</button>
<button type="button" id="delete-row-btn" onclick="deleteRow()">Delete last row</button>

{% endblock content %}
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import TariffCalcForm


def index(request):

    form = TariffCalcForm
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'clickapp/index.html', context)


def result(request):

    context = {}

    if request.method == 'POST':
        for r in request:
            form = TariffCalcForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                context['form'] = form
        return render(request, 'result.html', context)
    else:
        return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

**app.js**

```
function addRow() {

  const formTable = document.getElementById('table-id');
  const formRow = document.getElementById('table-row');
  const formRowCopy = formRow.cloneNode(true);
  formTable.appendChild(formRowCopy);

}
```

Comment: Have a look at [formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/formsets/).

Comment: @dgw Thank you for the suggestion. Formsets would require that I create a model which would save the input to a database, no? I'd like to process the data without having to store it (if possible). EDIT: I'm not sure if Formsets allow for dynamic forms either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [form wizard](https://django-formtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wizard.html) may be appropriate. It allows you to progress through a sequence of forms, storing the results of submitting each in the client's session. This is of course in the database, but it can be made transient, and can be an anonymous session. The final submit can process the data from all the forms and delete it from the session (which may be automatic, not sure) before rendering a results page for the user.

There is limited  capacity for skipping some forms based on the data in the previous ones.

The other approach is to go client-based. You use one huge form, but with Javascript of some sort to steer the user through it section by section. "Submit" on earlier parts does not  involve the server, but just hides the sub-form and reveals the next (or switches between tabs, which the user may also do for himself). Methods can range from simple Jquery up to enormous Javascript frameworks.